# Maintain data in R package with scheduled sql pulls

Tags: r, r-package

I have a personal, non-CRAN, R package. Its purpose is reduce the amount of repeated wrangling I need to do. The data must be pulled from sql server. This pull from SQL is done weekly. Where should I put my sql file and where should I put the R code that does a scheduled weekly sql pull?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Can you just use `read.csv('path to data')` in your code?

Anyway, some packages that have been useful to be for this purpose are `DataCache` for refreshing data on a schedule, `RODBC` for hooking SQL directly to R, thus avoiding the need to save SQL data separately, and `cronR` for scheduling R code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you use SQL to pull data from somewhere? What is your data source? Or do you mean you write SQL to create data?

Without knowing the specific, you have 2 options:
1. You could use RODBC package and use `sqlQuery()` e.g.

```
Data<- sqlQuery(odbcDriverConnect(...),paste("SELECT 
                            *
                          FROM DTtest;"))
```

to 'call' your data from your data source using SQL. More information you can find: https://www.statmethods.net/input/dbinterface.html
This way, you do not need to worry about where to save your sql file (I assume you mean the data). In this case, you only need to make sure your working directory is properly linked to your R script or at least where your R output wants to be in.

2. Assuming, you have a SQL script to pull data from somewhere else, you can windows scheduler or any types of scheduler to schedule and run the script and make the output saved in one folder where you also use R to grab the data from that directory.

Comment: point 2 was what I was looking for. The SQL file is a `.sql` not data, but I guess I could also put that code in a sqlQuery function.

Comment: @Alex Yes, you can do that. I think it also depends on how complex your SQL query is, sometimes running SQL query in R does not work. So I suggest you to do heavy stuff and create a table in your database, then use SQL to pull (select xxx from xxx) data through R is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make a chron task which will load the package, pull the data (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages)) and recompile the package.